# C++ function pointer to member function inside class

Tags: c++, function, pointers, compiler-errors

I'd like to store a function pointer to a private member function of my object inside my class.
Basically I want to do this:

```
MyWindow::MyWindow()
{
  std::function<void(int&)> func = this->memberFunction; // ERROR
}

void MyWindow::memberFunction(int& i)
{
  // do something
}
```

When I try to build it the compiler throws an error:

```
Error C3867: 'MyWindow::memberFunction': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message for C3867 tells you the first problem: you need to use `&` to form a function pointer.

Your next problem is that you do not have a function pointer, but a pointer-to-*member*-function, and that is not compatible with your `std::function`, which is missing anywhere to store or pass the implicit first argument that holds the "this" pointer.

You can, however, "bind" a value for that argument, in effect hardcoding it into the functor.

You're also going to need to spell it `MyWindow::memberFunction` rather than `this->memberFunction`, because that's just the way it is (to quote GCC: "ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function").

So:

```
using std::placeholders;
std::function<void(int&)> func = std::bind(&MyWindow::memberFunction, this, _1);
```

Or, using modern techniques:

```
std::function<void(int&)> func = [this](int& x) { memberFunction(x); };
```

Or just:

```
auto func = [this](int& x) { memberFunction(x); };
```

Comment: Yikes, I'm not keeping up with c++ syntactic sugar, but it looks like Perl devotees have taken over the ANSI steering committee!

Comment: I'd recommend using `&MyWindow::memberFunction` instead of `&this->memberFunction` for emphasizing that member function body is the one for all objects and has the same address. Moreover I'm not sure `&this->memberFunction` is valid at all

Comment: Using default capture by copy to only capture `this` seems a bit strange. As I understand it, that behavior will be deprecated in `c++20` according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: @super True - habit. Perhaps `[this]` would have been better. FWIW I never found it strange - `this` is indeed (or should be) captured by copy (though `*this` wouldn't be)